# Open source library to get geotags from images?

Tags: image-processing, open-source, exif, xmp, geotagging

Is there an open source library to efficiently and reliably get geotags from an image?

I want something system agnostic, hence a library instead of a program. I would love something well documented and in Python but any language works.

I'm not looking for exif reader per se, not all geotags are stored in exif. I want something that can find geotags independent of how they are stored in the image's metadata.

Comment: Try exiv2(C++), exiftool/imagemagick(bash), metadata-extractor(Java). Sorry, dont know any for python.

Comment: Those look like run of the mill metadata readers, do you know any that focus specifically on geotags? Or do I have to build something custom on top of one of those libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I maintain the *MetadataExtractor* library which supports GPS data along with many other kinds of metadata.

It has implementations in:

- Java https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor
- .NET https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet

Here's a sample that produces a Google Map from a batch of images:

https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor/blob/master/Samples/com/drew/metadata/GeoTagMapBuilder.java

Comment: That looks great, can your library do batch image reading? I need something that can potentially do thousands of images.

Comment: Sure. It's threadsafe so you can use it in parallel if you like. For regression testing, it's run over 2GB+ of files in under ten seconds. Apparently a news organisation used it on over a million images in one hit. At any rate, it should be quick to test whether it suits your purpose.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to hear. Is there an in depth documentation for the library?

Comment: I'll admit that documentation could be improved. There's info on the wiki, and the API is generally well documented. But most use cases are straightforward and I see few questions about it's use. Use the `metadata-extractor` tag on SO for questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org) (even though it may be overkill).

> The Geospatial Data Abstraction Library (GDAL) is a computer software library for reading and writing raster and vector geospatial data formats, and is released under the permissive X/MIT style free software license by the Open Source Geospatial Foundation.

The advantage of GDAL is that it supports a [huge number of geotagged formats](http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html).

If you want to do a quick test on your data, there is [an utility app](http://www.gdal.org/gdalinfo.html) that should print what you want.